# Fastest way to get a dictionary of counts of objects between 2 pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have two equal length lists: ss and ee. Each contain values such that ss[i] >= ee[i] and ss[i+1] >= ee[i] is true for all i.

For example:

```py
ss = [0,10,20,30]
ee = [3,15,23,40]

vals = [0,1,2,5,7,10,11,16,21,22,23,29,31,35,45]
```

I want to return a dictionary of counts where the keys are the values of ss, and the values are the counts of vals that fall between ss and its corresponding values.

for the first iteration, the values of vals between 0 and 3 (inclusive) are 0,1,2 so the key of 0 would have a value of 3.

Here is the desired output for my examples: `{0: 3, 10: 2, 20: 3, 30: 2}`

Here is my latest attempt:

```py
dCounts = {}
iv = 0
for i,e in enumerate(ss):
    count = 0
    s1 = e
    s2 = ee[i]
    while vals[iv] < s1:
        iv += 1
    while vals[iv] <= s2:
        iv += 1
        count += 1
    dCounts[s1] = count
```

if len(ss) = n, and len(vals) = m, then I think this runs in roughly O(m + n) time.

I can't think of a faster way to do it than that. I think I'm at the mercy of python's indexing for large lists though.

I've given this problem as simple python for clarity, but I'm really working with pandas series with datetime indices. I've been trying to leverage the speed I usually get out of pandas but can't seem to get anything fast enough to parse my large (~200,000) vectors in reasonable time.

I can't think of a good way to not have to interpret each time through the loop. I tried putting ss and ee into a data frame and using the .loc method on vals inside an apply function, but that performed worse than anything else I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
out = pd.cut(vals, bins=pd.IntervalIndex([pd.Interval(s, e, closed='both')
                                          for s, e in zip(ss, ee)])
             ).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
[0, 3]      3
[10, 15]    2
[20, 23]    3
[30, 40]    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Or with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
# ee must be sorted!
ss_arr = np.array(ss)
idx = np.searchsorted(ee, vals)

# remove 
m = idx<len(ss)
m2 = np.array(vals)[m] >= ss_arr[idx[m]]
idx2, cnt = np.unique(idx[m][m2], return_counts=True)
out = dict(zip(ss_arr[idx2], cnt))
```

Output: `{0: 3, 10: 2, 20: 3, 30: 2}`

Comment: I tested this and can confirm its about 4 times faster than using a loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this well,

```
count_list = [sum(i in range(ele1,ele2+1) for i in vals) for ele1, ele2 in zip(ss, ee)]
result = dict(zip(ss, count_list))
```

the count_list is,

```
[3, 2, 3, 2]
```

result is ,

```
{0: 3, 10: 2, 20: 3, 30: 2}
```